# Start Sound on BroadCast Recieving in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, broadcastreceiver

### MainActivity.cs

```
 private void StartAlarm() 
    {
        Intent myIntent;
        PendingIntent pendingIntent; myIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(AlarmToastReceiver));
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
        alarm_manager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, calndr.TimeInMillis, pendingIntent);
    }
```

### AlarmToastReceiver.cs

```
 [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled =true)]
public class AlarmToastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(context, "THIS IS MY ALARM", ToastLength.Long).Show();
    }
}
```

I am going to create an Alaram App in Xamarin. So here i pick the Time from TimePicker, and then and set the Alaram Manager Instance. When the Pending Intent completed , then BroadCastReceiver is active, and a Message is Shown to me,i.e "THIS IS MY ALARM", but here i want to Start Some Kind of Sound, i.e Animal Sound,Bird Sound etc.So how i can do it,can any one help me?thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MediaPlugin documented [here](https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager).

Here is nice [blog post](https://blog.xamarin.com/play-audio-and-video-with-the-mediamanager-plugin-for-xamarin/), which I reccomend to read.